# What is $E[X | X+Y= 1]$ where $X,Y$ are normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, gaussian

I saw this question posted on a non-english website, but the only information provided was $X,Y$ are normal random variables, what is

$E[X | X+Y= 1]$? And some people were saying the answer is 0.5.

You would at least have to know the mean and standard deviation of each $X,Y$ to find a closed form solution for this right? And I think you would need to know whether $X,Y$ are independent?

If we assume that $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$, standard normal, how do we solve for the conditional expectation?

I tried to think about it the following way:
$$
E[X | X+Y = 1] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_X(x|x+y=1) dx \\
f_X(x|x+y=1) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x, x+y= 1)}{P(X+Y=1)}
$$

But this doesn't really make sense because $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, so $P(X+Y=  1) = 0$. Any suggestions on how to proceed under the assumptions that $X,Y$ are standard normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is
$$E[X+Y \mid X+Y = 1] = E[X \mid X+Y = 1] + E[Y \mid X+Y = 1].$$
This equality requires no distributional assumptions about $X$ and $Y$; they need not be normal, and they can even be dependent.

The left-hand side equals $1$. If you have the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are exchangeable (i.e. $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,X)$) then the two terms on the right-hand side are equal and must each equal $1/2$.

Comment: First time I heard of the term "exchangeable." Is there a dumber way to solve this problem without using the exchangeable assumption?

Comment: @dd22205 In your problem you assume $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$ so exchangeability is satisfied and you can use the above argument. The only other approaches that I can think of involve getting into the grimy details of conditional normal distributions.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand exchangeability correctly (briefly read wiki article). Essentially if you have a set of random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ and a joint pdf $f_{X_1, \ldots, X_N}$, any permutation of the ordering of the arguments does not change the pdf, and thus, the expected value of each variable is the same?

Comment: @dd22205 Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are exchangeable, then the answer is necessarily $1/2$ regardless of the distribution (assuming all the relevant expectations exist). This is because $E(X \mid X + Y = 1) = E(Y \mid X + Y = 1)$ by exchangeability, and you get 1 if you add the left and right side together.

Comment: Is the "normally distributed" part a red herring?

Answer (score 1):

$$E(X+Y|X+Y=1)=1$$
$$E(X|X+Y=1)+E(Y|X+Y=1) = 1$$
By symmetry
$$E(X|X+Y=1)=E(Y|X+Y=1) = \frac{1}{2}$$